# Redux is executing the wrong action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to execute the `submitRecord` action that POSTs data to a server. It is supposed to activate the `SubmitRecordSuccess` upon doing it so the data is posted to the server but is the `SubmitRecordFail` action that is executed instead as if the app wouldn't had posted the data to the server. However, when I check the data is online. What I'm a doing wrong so the wrong action is executed?

This is the action:

```
export const submitRecordSuccess = ( id, recordData ) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_RECORD_SUCCESS,
    recordId: id,
    recordData: recordData
  };
};

export const submitRecordFail = ( error ) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_RECORD_FAIL,
    error: error
  };
};

export const submitRecordStart = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.SUBMIT_RECORD_START
  };
};

export const submitRecord = ( recordData ) =>{
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(submitRecordStart());
    axios.post( '/medicalRecords.json', recordData ).then( response => {
      dispatch(submitRecordSuccess( response.data, recordData ));
    } ).catch( error => {
      dispatch(submitRecordFail( error ));
    })
  }
}
```

And this is the function that dispatches the action:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSubmitRecord: (recordData) => dispatch(actions.submitRecord(recordData))
  };
};
```

Finally, this is the reducer:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SUBMIT_RECORD_START:
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true
    };

    case actionTypes.SUBMIT_RECORD_SUCCESS:
    const newRecord = {
      ...action.recordData,
      id: action.recordId
    }

    return {
      ...state,
      medicalRecords: state.orders.concat(newRecord),
      loading: false,
    };

    case actionTypes.SUBMIT_RECORD_FAIL:
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: false
    };

    default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

I console.log the error inside the `.catch()` and get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
>       at reducer (recordBuilder.js:24)

Comment: Please explore the error before dispatching the `submitRecordFail`. If possible, please share the error, it is throwing and add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks for that, can you also please share the definition of action `submitRecordStart`

Comment: It seems like the problem is when I create the newRecord variable in the reducer but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. See `spread` operator is actually `concat`, so your flow is going somewhere where you are using spread operator on an undefined variable. I know you trimmed down the code to post here, but can you please confirm, in reducer, you have `initialState` defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes I defined `medicalRecords` to an empty Array

Comment: Oh, you mean something like this `initialState  = { medicalRecords = [] }`?

Comment: Yes my initial state is the following `const initialState = {
  medicalRecords: [],
  loading: false
};`

Comment: Thank you very much I've been looking for the error for hours

Comment: Please, consider reading this, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352126/is-it-the-correct-way-to-upvote-an-answer

Comment: I already upvoted it but since I’m lees than 15 reputation my upvotes don’t reflect publicly although they are recorded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you state is initialised as:

```js
state = {
    medicalRecords: [],
    loading: false,
}
```

You are getting the error because of this line.

```js
medicalRecords: state.orders.concat(newRecord),
```

You are trying to access `state.orders` which is `undefined` and hence the error.

Please either add `order: []` in `initialState` or use

```js
medicalRecords: state.medicalRecords.concat(newRecord),
```

you can use spread operator for destructuring array also.

```js
medicalRecords: [ ...state.medicalRecords, newRecord ],
```